# Когда я хочу сменить значение в инпуте, то курсор после удаления первого элемента прыгает в конец, как отменить такое поведение после смены значения?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Мне нужно чтобы после удаления первого символа - я мог дальше спокойно редактировать инпут с этого же места. Вот как сейчас это работает..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Родительский компонент:
**Сам элемент в разметки:**

```
<LimChanger
                    loading={loadingSendLims}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    cantEdit={messageTextLims}
                    cancel={this.cancelChangeLims}
                    send={this.sendLims}
                    message={messageTextLims}
                    changed={(currentMaxLimChange !== null && currentMaxLimChange !== String(offer.maxAmount))
                      || (currentMinLimChange !== null && currentMinLimChange !== String(offer.minAmount))}
                    minLim={currentMinLimChange !== null ? currentMinLimChange : offer.minAmount}
                    maxLim={this.state.maxLimInput}
                  />
```

**Функция которая передается в onChange**

```
changeHandler = (e): void => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    const num = Number(value);
    const isValid = !isNaN(num);
    // что-то делаем с валидным / невалидным
    if (isValid) {
    // @ts-ignore
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: value});
    } else {
      console.log('invalid');
    }
  }
```

**Функция которая передается в cancel**

```
cancelChangeLims = (): void => {
    this.setState({
      currentMinLimChange: null,
      maxLimInput: 0,
    });
  }
```

**Функция которая передается в send**

```
    sendLims = (): void => {
        const {currentMinLimChange, maxLimInput} = this.state;
        const {offer, t} = this.props;
        this.setState({loadingSendLims: true});
        const prevMinLim = offer.minAmount;
        const prevMaxLim = offer.maxAmount;
        const newMinLim = parseFloat(String(currentMinLimChange));
        const newMaxLim = parseFloat(String(maxLimInput));
        const sendObj: Record<string, number | string | boolean> = {};
        if (prevMinLim !== newMinLim && newMinLim) sendObj.minAmount = newMinLim;
        else sendObj.minAmount = prevMinLim;
        if (prevMaxLim !== newMaxLim && newMaxLim) sendObj.maxAmount = newMaxLim;
        else sendObj.maxAmount = prevMaxLim;
    
        if (sendObj.maxAmount <= sendObj.minAmount) {
          this.setState({
            currentMinLimChange: null,
            maxLimInput: 0,
            messageTextLims: t('oneOffer.limitsValidationErrorMessage'),
          }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {this.setState({messageTextLims: ''});}, 2400);
          });
          return;
        }
    
        const errorCallback = (e?: Error): void => {
          this.setState({
            currentMinLimChange: null,
            maxLimInput: 0,
            loadingSendLims: false,
            messageTextLims: t('common.error'),
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({messageTextLims: ''});
          }, 1800);
    
          if (e) {
            this.props.setError?.(e.toString());
            throw e;
          }
        };
    
        putData (`/api/postings/${offer.exchange}/${offer.id}/settings/exchange`, sendObj).then(response => {
          if (response.success) {
            this.setState({
              currentMinLimChange: null,
              maxLimInput: 0,
              loadingSendLims: false,
              messageTextLims: t('oneOffer.limitsUpdated'),
            }, () => {
              setTimeout(() => {this.setState({messageTextLims: ''});}, 1800);
              if (prevMinLim !== newMinLim && newMinLim) this.props.updateOfferExchangeData?.(offer.id, 'minAmount', newMinLim);
              if (prevMaxLim !== newMaxLim && newMaxLim) this.props.updateOfferExchangeData?.(offer.id, 'maxAmount', newMaxLim);
              this.prepareData();
            });
    
            return;
          }
    
          if (response.error) {
            this.props.setError?.(response.error);
          }
          e

rrorCallback();
    }).catch(errorCallback);
  }
```

**Сам инпут в дочернем компоненте**

```
<input
            autoComplete="off"
            className="classic_input limit_changer_input"
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
            ref={ref => this.ref = ref}
            name="maxLimInput"
            onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e, this.ref)}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder || ''}
            value={this.state.maxLim}
          />
```

Как мне сделать нормальное поведение инпута, без перескакивания в начало?

Comment: К сожалению, абсолютно не разбираюсь в React.js, но попробую предложить решение: в момент, когда изменяет поле, запоминайте начальное положение каретки. А после проделанных изменений установить в это самое начальное положение. То есть: полагаю в функции `changeHandler` первой строкой прописать что-то типа `const startCursor = e.target.selectionStart`, а последней строкой - `e.target.setSelectionRange(startCursor, startCursor);`

Comment: Надеюсь, `e.target` - это тот самый `input` в данном случае). Главное, чтобы в методе `setSelectionRange(start, end)` и `start`, и`end` были равны

Comment: все равно сбрасывает в начало..